# Passbook pass signing - WWDR certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, passbook

I'm currently working on a web interface where people can create passes. These passes gets signed by a certificate from me, but now I want to add a feature so people can upload their own certificate.

I was looking at passk.it and there it isn't required to upload your own WWDR certificate when you want to sign with a custom certificate; you only have to upload the pass certificate. Does this mean that a Passbook pass can be signed by any WWDR certificate? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WWDR cert is the same for everyone, created by Apple. It must be added to the signing stack but you don't need to ask everyone to upload their own copy.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the answer I was looking for :)